# 2d vector equal subset sums

Tags: probability, combinatorics

I came across this question:

Let $v_1=(x_1,y_1),..., v_n=(x_n,y_n)$ be $n$ two dimensional vectors such that each $x_i$ and $y_i$ is an integer whose absolute value does not exceed $\frac{2^{n/2}}{100\sqrt{n}}$. Prove there are two disjoint sets $I,J$ in $\{1,2,...,n\}$ such that $$\sum_{i\in I}v_i=\sum_{j\in J}v_j.$$

Im thinking about calculating the L2 norm variance and expectation, and using Chebyshev inequality afterwards, but im not sure if this is correct.
Does anyone know how to solve this?

Comment: This is answered in https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1182797/disjoint-sets-with-the-same-sum